# Django Model field name translation

Tags: python, django, translation

I am doing a website in Django where I have a customview, deleteview and so on.
My problem is that I have written my apps in English and want the program to understand that when I print it out in a template it should be in another language. So I want to write some kind of translation. But all the tutorials I have found is how you translate the values you put inside your model and not the field name. Some one who has a tip on a link or how I should make the translation?

Comment: You want to translate the data that goes in the database? Have a look at [Django Hvad](http://django-hvad.readthedocs.org/)

Comment: No not the data, i want to translate the field name so when i make a form from the database the "titles" of the inputs should be in right language.

Answer (score 2):

See the `verbose_name` of Model itself and the `verbose_name` and `verbose_name_plural` class Meta additionally.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.CharField(_("My field"), max_length=255)
    my_another_field = models.CharField(_("My another field"), max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("My model")
        verbose_name_plural = _("My models")
```

Comment: I understand that but that is just how you write in plural or not? Or does it work the sam way with languages?

Comment: Do you need it in a form view?

Comment: No i just wnat that I can go into for example: Update Profile,
and there i want the option to update my password.

Comment: Yes. Ok, so it's some sort of a view where you need to show forms.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/

    from django.utils.translation import activate

and somewhere in your view, do as follows:

    activate('nl') # Activate Dutch

Then your form would be rendered in a given language.